# Start multiple threads without joining

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

(how) can i start multiple threads like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   std::thread (myfunction, i, param2, param3);
}
```

without joining?

Comment: Just like that. Joining doesn't start the threads. It blocks until they are done.

Comment: when i to it like this, i get a debug error in Visual Studio... R6010 abort() has been called :(

Comment: You need to either join or detach from the thread before you leave the threads scope. Just beware that once you detach you can't join later. I would suggest sticking the thread objects in a vector and the join later on.

Comment: About detaching threads, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach

Comment: thank you very much, all, escpecially stefaanv and John5342!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    std::thread{myfunction, i, param2, param3}.detach();
}
```

Or if you want to join the threads later, then put them in a `std::vector`.

```
std::vector<std::thread> v;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    v.emplace_back(myfunction, i, param2, param3);
}

// Do something else...

for (auto& t : v) {
    t.join();
}
```

Comment: threads start when they are added to vector, I think - would it be possible to add them without starting them?

Comment: @serup A thread of execution will start when the thread object is finished constructing. Have a look at std::async for lazy evaluation. Alternatively store the callables instead, and create the threads when you want to start.

Answer (score 7):

Simply don't call `join()`, `detach()` instead.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain the detach() in a bit more detail

Comment: detach() allow the thread to run independently. join() will block parent thread until it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can create some threads without joining them, just like what you do:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  std::thread my_thread {myfunction, i, param2, param3};
}
```

Once a thread is created, it starts being scheduled to run or wait. However, I advise you not doing that.

The meaning of "join" is to require the current thread to wait for the thread you called join on. For example,

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <thread> 
using namespace std; 

// A dummy function 
void foo(int n) 
{ 
  cout << "This is a dummy function." << endl; 
}

// Another dummy function
void bar(char c) {
  cout << "This is another dummy function." << endl;
} 

int main() 
{
  thread foo_thread(foo, 2); 
  thread bar_thread(bar, 'x');

  foo_thread.join();  // wait for foo_thread to finish
  bar_thread.join();  // wait for bar_thread to finish

  return 0; 
}
```

The main thread will sleep until the foo_thread and bar_thread finish.

If you remove foo_thread.join() and bar_thread.join(), the main thread may finish and return before foo and bar. This will cause your program crash. Because at the end of main function, destructors of foo_thread and bar_thread are invoked, and the destructor of std::thread will check whether this thread is joinable. If the thread is not detached, it is joinable. And if the thread is joinable, the destructor will invoke std::terminate(), so your program crashes.

Comment: why would the destructor call `std::terminate`? the destructor of joinable thread calls `join`, so this program should behave exactly the same even if you remove `foo_thread.join()` and `bar_thread.join()`

Comment: @Ap31 No, the destructor of joinable thread doesn't call join(). According to C++11 spec 30.3.1.3, "If joinable(), calls std::terminate(). Otherwise, has no effects". So if you remove foo_thread.join() and bar_thread.join(), the program is terminated.